# Moore Neighborhood in a matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, computer-science

I have a 2d text file converted from a image(the shape of 5 in this case) and I'm trying to implement Moore Neighborhood Trace algorithm.
The problem is that when i reach a point in the middle of the matrix my program starts visiting cells that have been visited before never reaching the bottom of the matrix.
My input:

```
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00001111111111100000
00001111111111100000
00001100000000000000
00001111111110000000
00001111111111100000
00000000000001110000
00000000000000110000
00011000000000110000
00011100000001110000
00001111111111110000
00000111111111000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

My output( 'x' is the border , A is the cell where I am after N iterations)

```
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000xxxxxxxxxx00000
000011111111111x0000
000011111111111x0000
000011xxxxxxxxx00000
0000111111111x000000
000011111111A1100000
000000000000x1110000
00000000000000110000
00011000000000110000
00011100000001110000
00001111111111110000
00000111111111000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
00000000000000000000
```

I manage to find at which iteration the problem occurs (n=29) after that it starts going up again

```
    class parse:

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 3 #entered from W so start looking from N-E-S-W
        self.matrix = self.read_file()
        self.process()
        self.save_file()

    #Handle Files I/0
    def read_file(self):
        ls = []
        with open("in","r") as g:
            tmp = g.readlines()

            for x in tmp:
                ls.append( [str(x[l]) for l in xrange(len(x))] )

        return ls


    def save_file(self):
        with open("out","w") as g:
            for i in xrange(len(self.matrix)):
                for j in xrange(len(self.matrix)):
                    g.write(self.matrix[i][j])
                g.write('\n')

    #End File Handle


    #Trace Algorithm
    #non-negative x

    def start_pixels(self):

        for x in xrange(len(self.matrix)):
            for y in xrange(len(self.matrix)):

                if self.matrix[x][y] == '1':

                    return [x,y]

    def process(self):
        init_point = self.start_pixels()

        start = self.step(init_point[0], init_point[1])
        i = 0 # iterations

        while i < 29:

            tmp = self.step(start[0],start[1])

            start= tmp

            i+=1

        self.matrix[start[0]][start[1]] = 'A' #current cell 
        print self.state #print the direction to skip

    def step(self,r,c):
        pos = [ [-1,0], [0,+1], [+1,0], [0,-1] ]  #search in the 4 directions of the cell N-E-S-W

        for p in xrange(len(pos)):

            sc = (p + self.state)%4 #start from the next direction clockwise from which was entered

            x = pos[sc][0] + r
            y = pos[sc][1] + c


            #if the cell is 1 search its neighborhood
            if self.matrix[x][y] == '1':
                self.neighborhod(x,y)
                return [x, y]


    #complete 0 cells with 1 relative to the cell
    def neighborhod(self,r,c):
        pos = [ [-1,0], [0,+1], [+1,0], [0,-1] ] #search in the 4 directions of the cell N-E-S-W

        for p in xrange(len(pos)):

            x = pos[p][0] + r
            y = pos[p][1] + c


            if self.matrix[x][y] != '1':
                self.matrix[x][y] = 'x'
                self.state = p #assign the direction to skip



p = parse()
```

[image: Animated version]

(please ignore the green cells completion with orange, i wasn't unable to get rid of it)

Comment: You should start the logic trace by adding print statements to the active code.  Print out the values you're working with.  Include a unique label for each, so you can trace the command flow as well as data.  For instance, just before the "if" in neighborhood, try /// print "NEIGH", p, x, y ///

If you can't see the problem for yourself, then give us the new code and the output for the iterations just before and after the problem point.

Comment: Well I know what the problem is.The next direction to follow from 'A'  it's Left (because I already completed the DOWN cell 0  with 'x' )which is going back to the upper of the character.The problem is I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: That's the symptom, not the problem.  What causes the program to "move left" at that point, as opposed to the decision it )should_ make?  What values are the input to the decisions?  What are they and what should they be?  That's where the print statements come in.

Without documentation for the code, including descriptive variable names and function descriptions, I don't know that you'll get anyone else to dig through your logic.  For instance, describe the "state" (which seems to be an integer-coded direction) and the algorithm that drives its transitions.

Comment: Yep, that's unreadable, all it needs is a little Bolognese. Looks like step() only considers the four horizontal/vertical pixels, have you checked that your code actually looks at all *eight* adjacent pixels?

Comment: i will try to refactor the code and yes i only search in 4 directions

Comment: It doesn't need refactoring (yet), just better documentation and some print statements to ask a few well-placed questions.

Comment: The Moore Neighbourdhood algorithm you reference does involve looking at all eight connected pixels, and also remembering which pixel you were on to enter the next boundary pixel, for backtrace when you have finished the search at that pixel - so it needs a stack/list of previously visited locations. Also deciding when the algorithm has finished can be challenging. See http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html for discussion/demonstration of the algorithm and how to decide when to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the logic problem.  In neighborhod [sic], you give no thought to the overall direction of investigation.  Instead, you choose a '1' and then blindly select the first direction that has an adjacent '0'.  This means that when you walk into a spot with a thickness of 1 character, you run the risk of stumbling out the other side, breaking right through the "thin wall".

You can fix this with some trivial sense of wall recognition: the new step must be adjacent to the previous position.  Instead of starting to the left every time, start 45 or 90 degrees clockwise from your previous direction, cycling through the choices from there.

Another way is to detect the handful of possible "wall" shapes and set up simple recognition patterns to traverse them.  Grab the 3x3 matrix with your previous position P, current position C, and '1' markings.  Here's a sample pattern:

```
1P0    1x0
1C0 => 1P0
110    11C
```

Do these observations and suggestions get you moving?

Comment: I don't start from left every time.For example if my previous position was Left i would start from Top if prev was Top i would start from Right .... etc.

Comment: Good.  However, you still have that break-through problem.  What did the tracing print statements tell you about the way you choose the starting direction?

Comment: I choose the next direction adjacent to where I mark the border

Comment: Then why didn't it find that it had to back out of the acute corner?  Why did it overwrite a '1'?  Please post the output that validates your assertion of "adjacent".  [insert wry, supportive smile]  As I tell my students, if your program worked the way *you* think it should, you wouldn't be here asking for my help.  Let's ask the *program* what's going on .

Comment: Thanks now i finally fixed it.It was the way that i choose the next direction to go

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help, just resize the input  (width x 2 and height x 2), so it prevent "dead pixel", in my research, i used it, check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCgcEKfQ0ao